# Are there any Ethereum L2 projects that built based on the Parity Substrate framework?

Tags: layer-2, rollups

Substrate is a powerful framework that makes it easy to build a blockchain. I am more familiar with the substrate development than the Layer2. and am curious about why there are no Ethereum Layer2 rollup projects based on it (I did not find any now). Substrate can be EVM compatible by installing the frontier layer. In addtion, as a Substrate-Ethereum Layer2 chain, it can be upgraded to the parachain to share the Polkadot security, sounds like a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

There is an project called [Madara](https://github.com/keep-starknet-strange/madara) which is a Starknet sequencer, based on substrate.